# How to parse more then one JSON from TCP/IP server?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

How to parse more then one JSON which each ending with null character(through socket TCP/IP).

```
{"ObjectID":"UHJvY1dpcmVsZXNzTXNn","DeviceCode":"RUNEOjI=","ActiveInputNames":"Q2hlY2sgaW4gRmFpbA==","DeviceInputNo":"999999","Activation":false,"Reset":true,"LocationID":"","LocationGroupText":"","ProtocolText":"","CallBackNo":"OTE5MTgyNTcyMjQ5"}��{"ObjectID":"VFBpbmdPYmplY3Q="}��
```

As you can see the above response which has 2 **JSON's** each ending with null character...I can easily parse the single **JSON** but unable to parse more then one **JSON**..

It would be great if any one suggest any solutions!!

Comment: Could you split the string, by using the null character ?

Comment: @AntoineF But we have to check each character(until we get null) to split the string right? It may be more time consuming if I receive large JSON

Comment: If you're talking about Java, it doesn't care about null termination of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the json string using the `��` and loop through the array:

```
String s = "{\"ObjectID\":\"UHJvY1dpcmVsZXNzTXNn\",\"DeviceCode\":\"RUNEOjI=\",\"ActiveInputNames\":\"Q2hlY2sgaW4gRmFpbA==\",\"DeviceInputNo\":\"999999\",\"Activation\":false,\"Reset\":true,\"LocationID\":\"\",\"LocationGroupText\":\"\",\"ProtocolText\":\"\",\"CallBackNo\":\"OTE5MTgyNTcyMjQ5\"}��{\"ObjectID\":\"VFBpbmdPYmplY3Q=\"}��";
            String[] array = s.split("��");
            for (String string: array){
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(string);
                    //do what ever you want with this
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try according to that!

Comment: @MorrisonDanny glad it helped. please accept the answer by clicking on tick icon :)