# In iOS How do i parse more than one JSON packet through TCP/IP Server?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, tcp, socket.io

How to parse more then one JSON which each ending with null character(through socket TCP/IP).

```
{"ObjectID":"UHJvY1dpcmVsZXNzTXNn","DeviceCode":"RUNEOjI=","ActiveInputNames":"Q2hlY2sgaW4gRmFpbA==","DeviceInputNo":"999999","Activation":false,"Reset":true,"LocationID":"","LocationGroupText":"","ProtocolText":"","CallBackNo":"OTE5MTgyNTcyMjQ5"}��{"ObjectID":"VFBpbmdPYmplY3Q="}��
```

As you can see the above response which has 2 JSON's each ending with null character...I can easily parse the single JSON but unable to parse more then one JSON..

It would be great if any one suggest any solutions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all separate both the JSONs using `components(separatedBy:)` so we can parse them individually.

```
let str = """
{"ObjectID":"UHJvY1dpcmVsZXNzTXNn","DeviceCode":"RUNEOjI=","ActiveInputNames":"Q2hlY2sgaW4gRmFpbA==","DeviceInputNo":"999999","Activation":false,"Reset":true,"LocationID":"","LocationGroupText":"","ProtocolText":"","CallBackNo":"OTE5MTgyNTcyMjQ5"}��{"ObjectID":"VFBpbmdPYmplY3Q="}��
"""
let jsonArr = str.components(separatedBy: "��")
```

`jsonArr` contains both the *JSON `Strings`*. Let's see how we can parse them.

We'll use **`Codable`** to parse both the *JSONs* using the below **model**.

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let objectID: String
    let deviceCode: String?
    let activeInputNames: String?
    let deviceInputNo: String?
    let activation: Bool?
    let reset: Bool?
    let locationID: String?
    let locationGroupText: String?
    let protocolText: String?
    let callBackNo: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case objectID = "ObjectID"
        case deviceCode = "DeviceCode"
        case activeInputNames = "ActiveInputNames"
        case deviceInputNo = "DeviceInputNo"
        case activation = "Activation"
        case reset = "Reset"
        case locationID = "LocationID"
        case locationGroupText = "LocationGroupText"
        case protocolText = "ProtocolText"
        case callBackNo = "CallBackNo"
    }
}
```

**Parse** the `JSON`strings like,

```
let parsedObjs = jsonArr.map { (str) -> Root? in
    if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
            return obj
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

`parsedObjs` will contain *parsed `Root` objects* for both the *JSON `strings`*.

Let me know if there is any confusion left regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I answered the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56834220/2299040) in Android Yesterday. Here is the Swift Version

```
let s = "{\"ObjectID\":\"UHJvY1dpcmVsZXNzTXNn\",\"DeviceCode\":\"RUNEOjI=\",\"ActiveInputNames\":\"Q2hlY2sgaW4gRmFpbA==\",\"DeviceInputNo\":\"999999\",\"Activation\":false,\"Reset\":true,\"LocationID\":\"\",\"LocationGroupText\":\"\",\"ProtocolText\":\"\",\"CallBackNo\":\"OTE5MTgyNTcyMjQ5\"}��{\"ObjectID\":\"VFBpbmdPYmplY3Q=\"}��".components(separatedBy: "��")


            for string in s{
                // do your parsing here
                print(string)
            }
```

All you need to do is split the string with �� and you are good to go. Parse the JSON the way you used to.